# How to access browser's network headers data after getting redirected from payment gateway to my order confirmation page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paytm

I am working on payment gateway integration and my web site is on rails framework .
My problem is , when i am getting redirected to my payment confirmation page , there is some response coming with my giving callback url and that response has some vital information like payment is successful or not etc.

This network response i can see in chrome network header tab [under developer option (press f12)]

IMAGE -i have given link of image that shows - chrome's network tab that contains headers for order115 under that formdata is available that i need to fetch for payment confirmation

[image: i]
please look into the image for better understanding

is there any way to get this response in my rails App ?
i have tried with request.headers that does not contain this info .

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a controller action for your payment confirmation page where you can access this response data using `params` hash and after processing this data, render your order confirmation page

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply  but Paytm payment gateway just redirecting to my callback url, I can't see that in my params.    But I can see that in Chrome 's network tab under header' s tab there is a form data that contains vital information. That i need to verify that my transaction is happening successfully or not

Comment: I see that from form data, Paytm is not redirecting, but posting to /order115 with transaction details. So if configure paytm callback url to come back to any endpoint of your choice, There you will have formdata in `params`

Comment: thanks Sujan , Yeah they are posting and i am able access all params[:attr_name] directly in my controller